# Undefined Method in Form_For Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for, nested-form-for

I have a `post` model that `belongs_to` a `category` model. The post resources are nested under the category resources. I'm building out a `form_for @post` to create a new post. However, I'm getting the following error:

`undefined method 'posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd54ba33540>:0x007fd54c8e57c8>`

According to my routes, it should be pointing to the `new_category_post_path` but I'm not sure why it's not. I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037827/undefined-method-s-path-in-form-for) because it's very similar to my situation but to no avail. Any ideas?

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

**app/models/category.rb and post.rb:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController    
  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @post = @category.posts.new
  end
end
```

**views/posts/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%=f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title...' %>
  <%=f.text_area :content %>
  <%=f.submit 'Create post' %>
<% end %>
```

**rake routes:**

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
    category_posts GET    /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                   POST   /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                   PATCH  /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                   PUT    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                   DELETE /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
        categories GET    /categories(.:format)                             categories#index
                   POST   /categories(.:format)                             categories#create
      new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                         categories#new
     edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                    categories#edit
          category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#show
                   PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#update
                   PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#update
                   DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                         categories#destroy
              root GET    /                                                 categories#index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to nest your resources, then you need to make sure the URL which is generated in the form_for helper knows how to do that correctly.  In this case, you need to pass it 2 objects, the post object, and the category object.  The location is first, the new object is second in the array, so your form for will look more like:

```
<%= form_for [@category,@post] do |f| %>
  <%=f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title...' %>
  <%=f.text_area :content %>
  <%=f.submit 'Create post' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! At first, you missed the space after `form_for`, which didn't work. But I see you fixed it. This was the same solution as the one in the link I included. But for whatever reasons, when I tried it earlier, it didn't work.